# How to OR null values in Solr query with a range

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a query where `fq=score_dx:[0.0 TO 1]`

We need something like `score_dx:[0.0 TO 1] OR score_dx:''`

This is not working. How to do `OR null` with the existing `fq`?

Answer (score 3):

This is the way to go : `fq=(score_dx:[0.0 TO 1]) OR (*:* AND -score_dx:[* TO *])`

How does it work and why ? Here an explanation attempt  :

- Solr Standard Query Parser does not support searching a field for empty/null value. In this situation the filter needs to be negated, exluding documents having any value in the field, so that the query remains valid. To match any value, a [range query](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Standard+Query+Parser#TheStandardQueryParser-RangeSearches) should be used to prevent inconsitent behaviors when using wildcard with negative queries (the `[* TO *]` part).
- When applying a filter and a negated filter in the same `fq` param, you need to add `*:*` on the latter otherwise the OR won't apply properly (it would behave like a AND), but I can't explain why. It seems like the negated query needs a full result set to match against it, otherwise it would "intersect" with the previous filter results.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a negative clause such as `-field_name:*`

I hope that helps.

Comment: I am doing something like `score_dx:[0.2 TO 1]  OR (-score_dx:[* TO *] AND *:*)`. IT seems to work but I dont know what does this means ` (-score_dx:[* TO *] AND *:*)`?

Comment: why do not you use just  score_dx:[0.2 TO 1] OR (-score_dx:[* TO *])

Comment: Hi @user1324887, @ameertawfik, I just posted an answer explaining the `[* TO *]` and why we need to add `*:*` in the second filter.